# CONSULTAR DADOS A PARTIR DE UMA TABELA DE CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Eu tenho 3 tabelas em um banco de dados, uma abriga os dados dos clientes, outras dos produtos e uma das vendas, contendo a chave estrangeira do id da tabela produtos e clientes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu necessito fazer uma consulta que exiba as compras realizadas pelo cliente de ID = 2, mostrando seu nome e o nome do produto que ele comprou. A parte que me confundiu foi na hora de mostrar o nome do produto comprado, consegui realizar apenas a seguinte consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que essa consulta deve resolver:

```
select c.nome as 'cliente', p.nome as 'produto' from clientes c
join vendas v on v.idcliente = c.idcliente
join produtos p on p.idproduto = v.idproduto
where c.idcliente = 2
```

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou...

Answer (score 1):

Deve ser mais ou menos isso que você procura.

```
SELECT
    Cliente.NOME,
    Produto.NOME
FROM
    Vendas
        LEFT JOIN Cliente on (Vendas.IDCliente = Cliente.IDCliente)
        LEFT JOIN Cliente on (Vendas.IDProduto = Produto.IDProduto)
WHERE
    Cliente.IDCliente = 2
```